# Why HTML 5 still have support for Presentational elements?

Tags: xhtml, html, w3c, web-standards

See list here:

http://www.w3schools.com/html5/html5_reference.asp

like `<b>` , `<i>`, `<br>`, `<hr>`, `<small>`?

Is it means no cons to use these? But what about content and presentation seperation?

Comment: See also related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1743497/are-i-and-b-tags-actually-deprecated/

Comment: You need to mark more of your questions with an accepted answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Two reasons come to mind:

1. Because some people (not me, [here is a primer about this opinion](http://stellify.net/html5-b-and-i-tags-are-going-to-be-useful-read-semantic-again/) and [here are the WHATWG FAQ about this](https://github.com/whatwg/html/blob/master/FAQ.md#but-they-are-presentational)) don't think of them as presentational. They argue, that `<b>` has semantics of its own, for example, where `<strong>` is not right and the text should be bold anyways (IMHO therefore we have `<span>`)
2. Because HTML5 has a pragmatic and backwards compatible approach: What worked in HTML4 should work too in HTML5. They argue, that this is why XHTML2 died.

Comment: I would argue that `b` and `strong` have the same semantic meaning. `strong` is the result of over-purism imho. I never use `strong`, it's just more bytes for the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

First have a look what [WHATWG says about it](http://wiki.whatwg.org/wiki/FAQ#Why_are_some_presentational_elements_like_.3Cb.3E.2C_.3Ci.3E_and_.3Csmall.3E_still_included.3F) (this is also mentioned in the answer to the related question cited above).

It is said (as I thought, too) that [<strong>](http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/Overview.html#the-strong-element) and [<em>](http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/Overview.html#the-em-element) provide an emphasis when using a screen reader, but according to [this article](http://csswizardry.com/2010/01/a-reconsiderationin-defence-of-b-and-i-or-people-fear-what-they-dont-understand/) by Harry Roberts, it turns out that in practice screen readers don't accentuate text marked this way.

And last, read the spec about [<b>](http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/Overview.html#the-b-element) (it's already mentioned in the FAQ in the first link, above):

> The b  element represents  a span of
>   text to be stylistically offset from
>   the normal prose without conveying any
>   extra importance, such as key words in
>   a document abstract, product names in
>   a review, or other spans of text whose
>   typical typographic presentation is
>   boldened.

and [<i>](http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/Overview.html#the-i-element):

> The i  element represents  a span of
>   text in an alternate voice or mood, or
>   otherwise offset from the normal
>   prose, such as a taxonomic
>   designation, a technical term, an
>   idiomatic phrase from another
>   language, a thought, a ship name, or
>   some other prose whose typical
>   typographic presentation is
>   italicized.

Likewise, have a look at [<small>](http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/Overview.html#the-small-element), [<hr>](http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/Overview.html#the-hr-element) and [<br>](http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/Overview.html#the-br-element) (there are examples there, too.)

Answer (score 0):

They have also redefined the meaning and semantics of several of these elements. They realized the need for an element that does something like `<b>` and there was already an element, so they kept it, and preserved backwards compatibility, instead of introducing something new.