# Is it ok to use <strong> in place of <b> blindly?

Tags: html, xhtml, accessibility, web-standards, semantic-markup

**Note:** I know `<b>` is presentational and `<span style="font-weight:bold>` is a better way, and `<strong>` and `<em>` are for emphasis but my question is not regarding this.

---

Should we convert every `<b>` to `<strong>` blindly? Many people do this, they think `<b>` is not good as per web standards so they convert every `<b>` to `<strong>` upon site redesign, content re-population, new site design and people suggest this to others also.

---

Dreamweaver has also given the option to convert all `<b>` and `<i>` to `<strong>` and `<em>` on code paste in design view and when we use B and I Which people use blindly.

[alt text http://shup.com/Shup/280420/1101118332-My-Desktop.png](http://shup.com/Shup/280420/1101118332-My-Desktop.png)

And Dreamweaver (if above option is checked) and many online WYSIWYG editor give output in `<strong>` and `<em>` while button shows **B** and *I*.

[alt text http://shup.com/Shup/280425/1101118921-My-Desktop.png](http://shup.com/Shup/280425/1101118921-My-Desktop.png)

In my opinion it's creating a misconception about `<strong>` and `<b>`

---

When we get content from a client we don't know where the client wants to give emphasize and where he just wants to use bold text for presentation purposes. What should we do in this circumstance? No one has the time to give to decide for each instance (us and the client), whether it should be `<b>` or `<strong>`, `<i>` or `<em>`

What are the pros and cons to convert every `<b>` and `<i>` into `<strong>` and `<em>` blindly if we are saying our site is accessible?

---

**Update:** remember [`<b>` and `<i>` are not deprecated they are in HTML 5 specification](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2235450/why-html-5-still-have-support-for-presentational-elements)

Comment: You shouldn't ever do anything blindly ... especially in web design ;)

Comment: @sfussenegger - but people do.

Comment: `<span style="font-weight:bold>` is absolutely NOT better than `<b>` under any circumstances.

Comment: Related post - [What's the difference between <b> and <strong>, <i> and <em>?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/271743/465053)

Answer (score 33, accepted):

As others have mentioned, using `<strong>`, `<em>`, `<cite>` etc. adds semantics. This is important because you say something about why you want to emphasize something and increase the readability of your html, because you know why it's in bold.

Furthermore, screen readers use the strong tags to make an audible difference when reading it aloud.

Maybe you could think about the audio represenation as a guide. If you would want a difference when read aloud, for instance, mark it as `<strong>`. If not, use `<b>`.

Then there is the issue of rendering: I don't actually know if all browsers will render a `<strong>` as bold and if it will stay that way.

So in short: `<strong>`**No**`</strong>`.

Comment: can u make any mp3 clip and share a link of how screen reader read text in <strong> and <b>. or can u tell me how can i make

Comment: Theoretically, the user agents, including screen readers should diffrentiate these tags. But it's just a theory. Not tested on SO's markup, but I think there will be no difference too.

Answer (score 16):

> Is it ok to use `<strong>` in place of `<b>` **blindly**?

No.

To quote Anne van Kesteren ([source](http://annevankesteren.nl/2010/01/optimizing-html)):

> Let me give some contradictory advice. Please do replace `em` with `i` and `strong` with `b`. The resulting markup is likely more accurate. Especially with WYSIWYG software it is extremely unlikely they will be used correctly, but also **because the notion spread that they are interchangeable with the sole difference being that `strong` and `em` are semantic a lot of misuse happened**. When in doubt, use `i` and `b`.

And he’s right, of course. `strong` and `b` are not the same. `em` and `i` are not the same. Only use `strong` / `em` if you want to add semantical emphasis to text.

Comment: Which is almost always the reason we use <b> and <i>.

Comment: Late to this game, but I wanted to reify this answer because I believe it has the best advice of all the contributions. In XML content management that I work in, untrained writers often use markup for how it makes things appear rather than for what it represents semantically. In a corollary to Anne van Kesteren's advice above, semantic markup used wrongly is difficult to detect and fix because edits must be done by reading in context. My lemma to this corollary is that the variety of inventive tag abuse scenarios is n-squared the number of semantic elements available to abuse.

Comment: So when in doubt use <b> and not <strong> then?

Answer (score 7):

#### `<b>`, `<i>`, `<tt>` are strictly typographical.

By saying typographical, I don't mean visual. I mean semantics expressed by the look.
They need additional context to have specific meaning (eg. definition, like:

> - text in italics were taken from ...

or relying on typographic convention, like that the text in bold are eye-catchers and the italics mean context change). In typographical conventions bolds and italics are some kind of parenthesis nesting.

```
(for example [this one has another context])
```

**for example *this one has another context***

These tags are the port of traditional, printed typography, in which semantics is carried by the specific visual presentation.

As you pointed out, they are considered to be deprecated, but not in XHTML5. Why? I think, mostly that the web content is not only for the e-media. If you print web document, these tags may replace the syntax of some expressions used for example in `TeX`.

#### `<strong>` and `<em>` are strictly for semantics,

telling how the text should be read and emphasized.

So to recap, none of these tag means the same as other, so they not even *should not be* used, but **may not be** used interchangeably, nor substituted. In particular, blindly.

AFIR, Dreamweaver is not the model of the WYSIWYM editor. I have always considered it to be next generation of FrontPage thinking (ease of use and getting things done now, and forget about the future and scalability).

So I understand the surprise here, and your misconception feeling is right :)

Answer (score 4):

We shouldn't swap `b` and `strong` blindly as they have different intended purpose.

`<b`> and `<i>` are not presentational elements as per the HTML5 spec. They have a different meaning and purpose. Quoting the HTML5 specs,

> The **b** element represents a span of text to be stylistically offset
>   from the normal prose without conveying any extra importance, such as
>   key words in a document abstract, product names in a review, or other
>   spans of text whose typical typographic presentation is boldened.

and for the `i` element,

> The **i** element represents a span of text in an alternate voice or mood,
>   or otherwise offset from the normal prose, such as a taxonomic
>   designation, a technical term, an idiomatic phrase from another
>   language, a thought, a ship name, or some other prose whose typical
>   typographic presentation is italicized.

As others have very well clarified, `i` and `em` cannot be used interchangeably and so is the case with `b` and `strong`.

The usage of `i` and `b` for their intended purpose is very rare. (eg. in dialogue scripts, thesis, resumes)

---

References:

1. http://html5doctor.com/i-b-em-strong-element/
2. http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/text-level-semantics.html#the-i-element

Answer (score 2):

If you just want to use bold text, make it bold via css. If the "bold" font weight has no semantical meaning, you should not use `<strong>` or `<em>` for it. However, you shouldn't use `<b>` or `<i>` either because these are non-semantic (in fact they are font-style tags) and their use is thus [discouraged if not even deprecated](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/present/graphics.html#edef-B).

Comment: @hurkhan, they're not deprecated, where are you getting this information from?

Comment: @hurikhan77 The presentation layer (CSS) may be removed from the document, or changed by user, then your bold information will get lost. This is not a good advice. The question is about semantics, not the presentation.

Comment: @takeshin: but "bold information" is actually part of a presentation layer, isn't it? It has nothing to do with the emphasis of a word, this is what "strong" and "em" are for... So still: No, you should not use "b" for semantical meaning.

Comment: @hurikhan77 'Bold information' from your example is excactly as important as: `display: block; left: -999em;` or other rules. Eg. there was a big, bold sentence, saying 'Do not enter'. What is 'bold information then?' The default styles for elements which should be bold are bold (eg. h6). If you need to use inline bold text, you have to use additional tag. For adding styles to the part of the text, you need at least `<span>`, which will be invisible with no styles. Isn't `<b>` better in this case?

Comment: @takeshin I don't see any problem with removing bold fonts if you remove the presentation layer as long as it does not remove semantical information. If it is of typographical value/relevance you shouldn't remove the presentation layer anyway, just replace it with one that fits the situation better. And I think this is why the usage of `<b>` is discouraged (which does not necessarily mean deprecated, depending on the html profile used). That also means that these tags cannot replace each other (strong vs. b) and are not interchangeable. BTW `<h6>` has semantical meaning, may it be bold or not.

Comment: @hurrikhan77 I think we are arguing about the thinking about the information in the general, abstract way. E.g. storing the web page data in database, xml, json etc. This does not cover the *visual* 'boldness' at all. How do you add/remove 'boldness' then, not using CSS? Only by choosing specific tags.

Comment: @take I would conclude this discussion with "just think before use" because we are probably discussing the same intentions from different views.

Comment: @hurrikhan77 Agreed :) 'Think before use'.

Answer (score 1):

`<b>` and `<strong>` are not necessarily the same. `<strong>` as you suggested are for higher emphasis, while `<b>` are for styling purposes only. So you should not switch them blindly.

Some people will say that the `<b>` tag is being deprecated, but it's not. It's [still alive and kicking](http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/Overview.html#the-b-element). However; it is not very semantic, as you're saying, so it might be a better option to use a `<span>` and style it.

Comment: But the specs clearly state that UAs are no longer forced to display the <b> tag boldened - probably because its usage was discouraged in HTML4. So if one expects a special formatting, he/she needs to style the <b> tag by CSS accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

As others have said there's a semantic difference between strong/b and i/em. Especially they are used by screenreaders for visually impaired people visiting your website. For them it makes a huge difference if you just make some text bold-face, or if you want to add some kind of EMphasis to what you're saying on your website. So be sure to carefully consider making something bold using B or STRONG. The same goes for EM and I.

Answer (score 0):

There are some great answers here already, but for those of you that still don't quite understand and need a further explanation and example, I found a useful explanation of this in the [HTML Text, Web Platform Docs](http://docs.webplatform.org/wiki/guides/html_text) tutorial. The tutorial explains the difference in use between `<strong>` and `<b>` a little past halfway down the page and gives examples.

Comment: Your link is dead.

Answer (score 0):

To understand the difference between the `<b>` - `<strong>` and `<i>` - `<em>` tags, you need to understand that the  tag is used to simply highlight text, while `<strong>` defines the meaning of the highlighted text. Likewise with the `<i>` and `<em>` tags: an [example](https://domhtml.ru/en/tags-strong-b-html/) of the difference is the OS settings used by the visually impaired. When the reading of texts with the "speech" is enabled, the words will be highlighted by the intonation of the `<strong>` and `<em>` tags.