# Question of standards: I, EM, B, STRONG, BIG, SMALL

Tags: xhtml, html, standards, w3c

In real work, I always use EM for italics, STRONG for selection. And SMALL.

I decided to update their knowledge in HTML + decided to look towards the HTML 5

So, xHTML 1.0 strict, as the language of separating flies and cutlets, and allowed the following inline elements related to the text:

I, EM, B, STRONG, BIG, SMALL

here, I came across the first question - why the tags B and I have not been eliminated or at least not become deprecated in XHTML? After all, if you look at the DTD, then about the tag B & I is clearly written:

```
<! ELEMENT b% Inline;> <! - Bold font ->
<! ELEMENT i% Inline;> <! - Italic font ->
```

Is the fat content and courses are structural, logical feature? This is clearly a visual feature.

Next, I looked at http://www.w3schools.com/html5/html5_reference.asp and was surprised that the tag BIG somehow removed from the HTML5, and its logical equivalent SMALL - left! Although BIG was even in XHTML 1.0 Strict!

Where is the logic in such permutations? Explain.

Comment: `<b>` is not fat! It's just big-boned.

Comment: “the language of separating flies and cutlets” — if only they’d had that tagline five years ago, XHTML 2 might have gone somewhere.

Comment: @Pekka ROFL. I always wanted to use that reference somewhere!

Comment: Last time I checked, no one uses ALL CAPS for their tags, except for <!DOCTYPE>

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2235450/why-html-5-still-have-support-for-presentational-elements/2240579#2240579

Answer (score 5):

There *are* uses for tags such as `i` and `small` that are not presentational but semantic. `<small>` represents fine print (or legal print) and side comments. And `i` can be used for text that is traditionally italicized but not emphasized, e.g. book titles, foreign words, and Latin names of species.

As to why `<big>` has been dropped while `<small>` hasn't, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2260024/why-big-is-not-in-html-5-tag-list-while-small-is/2260045#2260045).

Comment: In HTML 4.x and earlier `i` and `small` are purely presentational. Readers might imply semantics from the presentation, but those semantics are not inherit in the elements. HTML5 is trying to redefine the meanings of these elements though (mutter mutter backwards compatibility mutter).

Comment: @David: yes, it is redefining the meaning, but only for those elements where this is possible. This is different from keeping tags just for the sake of backwards compatibility. Case in point: tags such as `center` or `font` have been dropped even though they are much more popular than `small` and are thus much more important in terms of backwards compatibility.

Comment: My comment about backwards compatibility was with regard to `small` and `i` meaning **different** things in HTML 4.x and HTML5. (And HTML5 handles backwards compatibility with font et al: http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/obsolete.html#font )

Comment: I don't think there's a backward compatibility problem with "small" or "i", because they only narrow the valid usage. Any semantic extractor will have to continue to use the v4.x definition, since it can't tell that the v5 meaning is in place, because html5 documents don't contain versioning information. "cite" on the other hand is real backwards-compatibility problem since the naming of a work in a cite tag can no longer be assumed to be a true citation.

Answer (score 4):

First of all EM is not for italics, it is for EMPHASIS. STRONG is for strong emphasis. You should never use them for any other purpose. Not according to the HTML 4 specs, XHTML or HTML5.

For presentational effects one should use **CSS**.

So why has B, I and SMALL been kept in HTML5?

1. To prevent abuse of EM and STRONG. If you can not use CSS, like on a forum or a wiki, it is better to use non semantic elements, than to abuse semantic ones. As in our comments for Stackoverflow, where I suspect em and strong is being abused a lot, thanks to the WYSIWYG editor we are using.
2. There might be legitimate reasons to use bold or italics besides what is covered by EM, STRONG and DFN. HTML5 defines this as text that should be spoken in different voice or mood, it thus adds a kind of semantic and a legitimate use case. This slight redefinition is controversial.
3. In lieu of B and I some software and/or users insert style-attributes. That is trading one evil for an even worse one.
4. The same applies to SMALL as well. It has received a similar use case, where it sort of carries a semantic meaning. It does **NOT** mean side commments.

BTW, B and I were not deprecated in HTML 4/XHTML 1.

Comment: +1 for point #3, which I'd say also applies to underlining (if a test, for example, instructs people to write a correct replacement for an underlined word or phrase, the underlining may have semantic rather than just presentational significance).

Answer (score 3):

> why the tags B and I have not been eliminated or at least not become deprecated in XHTML?

Nothing was deprecated in XHTML 1.0. It was designed to express HTML 4.01 in XML.

XHTML 1.1 only slightly tweaked it.

> Next, I looked at http://www.w3schools.com/html5/html5_reference.asp

No. Not W3Schools. Please no.

> and was surprised that the tag BIG somehow removed from the HTML5, and its logical equivalent SMALL - left!

The [semantics of small have been redefined](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/text-level-semantics.html#the-small-element). It will (if not changed before HTML5 becomes a recommendation) mean "side comments" and not "a reduced font size".

Answer (score 0):

Standards are more politics than logic reason.

Sign up to any w3 mailing list (personal favourite is *public-html*), sit back and enjoy(?) the reality soap.

Comment: -1 I disagree. After 7 years actively particpating in the international standards community, I have seen lots of politics and lots of common sense and logic. That is, the very same that you can see in most corporations and universities, for example. A sweeping statement like "Standards are more politics than logic reason." is an unfair overgeneralisation and is plainly wrong.

Comment: @CesarGon: I see you have not followed the last html5 <iframe doc=""> discussion at least =P Would make even the happiest optimist disillusioned. But I kind of was fishing for that -1 ^^

Comment: I don't doubt that politics dominate some situations. I myself have witnessed such situations in a number of forums. That is sad. But extrapolating from there and generalising that *all standards* are more politics than logic reason is unfair and incorrect. That is my point.

Answer (score 0):

I think, part of the answer about `<big>` and `<small>` can be found [in the spec](http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/Overview.html#the-small-element):

> The small element represents side comments such as small print.
>
> Note: Small print typically features disclaimers, caveats, legal restrictions, or copyrights. Small print is also sometimes used for attribution, or for satisfying licensing requirements.

So basically the semantics of `<small>` is “side comments” and “small print” (in the sense of disclaimers), which is encoded in HTML by an element named “small”. Maybe the naming should be better, of course.

Answer (score 0):

#### Why is `<small>` still in HTML5, but `<big>` isn’t?

I’d assume `<small>` is still around because it’s often used for side comments, disclaimers, etc in practice, and there isn’t an existing HTML element suited to the task.

Ian Hickson tried to design HTML5 based on how HTML was used in practice: paving the cowpaths. Thus there are places where logic is sacrificed for practicability. (As it says on [the WHATWG blog, “Please leave your sense of logic at the door, thanks!”](http://blog.whatwg.org/).

If people *are* already using `<small>` for side comments, and aren’t using `<big>` for anything meaningful (I say “if” as there’s plenty of room to debate and/or research that), then why not enshrine the common usage of the former in the spec, and remove the latter?

#### Why are `<b>` and `<i>` still in HTML5 if they’re purely visual in effect?

`<b>` and `<i>` have been redefined to have meaning in HTML5, although it’s a very light form of meaning:

- [`<i>`: “a span of text in an alternate voice or mood”](http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec-author-view/the-i-element.html#the-i-element)
- [`<b>`: “a span of text to which attention is being drawn for utilitarian purposes”](http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec-author-view/the-b-element.html#the-b-element)

They’re now general purpose elements, to be used to distinguish runs of text for reasons not covered specifically by another tag.

Answer (score 0):

I believe Hickson should stick to use "style" for changing font sizes, not using those "big" and "small" tags.

To maintain "small" and remove "big" is just so wrong.

Comment: That doesn't answer the question though

Comment: But in HTML5, `<small>` isn’t for changing font size. It’s for side comments, disclaimers and the like.

Comment: I know, but the result is ALSO a style change. I think the tag has been named not in the best way to suite it's purpose.
It drives people off, particularly if you don't always have the time to travel through the gigantic HTML 5 specs.

Answer (score 0):

Personally I'm happy with this state — there are some conventions (semantics) around "small print" and that tag works quite nicely for it. If I said "read the small print" in a conversation, that would make sense, but "read the big print" and you'd be thinking "what's 'big print'?" I'm happy to see big go (never use it) and small stay (use it often).

I don't personally use b, finding strong suits my needs there. But there are cases where you want text italicised but not emphasised. If it's emphasis, I use EM. If it's a citation, I use CITE. If it's some other italics convention, I don't want to misuse EM or CITE.

Wikipedia has some notes on when to use italics, and you'll find some notes here on the various HTML tags that could be used with those examples:
http://www.w3.org/html/wg/wiki/Guide/italics#General_Examples

Feel free to debate any or all examples. It was just my stab at it. Some are straightforward (e.g. use of EM), others are somewhat ambiguous. I prefer to use I for italics rather than choose (a) EM, where that would be misuse or (b) SPAN with font-style italic, which carries NO semantic meaning.

The fact is there are semantics attached to use of italic test (in English at least) and HTML does not provide custom elements to deal with all of them, nor does it need to imho. I is a suitable middle ground.

And for anyone who dislikes using it, you never have to! It's not mandatory :)

Answer (score 0):

Oh, the irony: "fine print" is metonimy for something purely presentational, usually carrying just-as-important information but made harder to read in order to decieve the reader into skipping it. Back in the day of print, it would have been a purely 'CSS' job.